# Using cut multiple times and concatenating the results using multiple delimiters?

Tags: bash, awk, delimiter, paste, cut

If I have a file:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
```

And I only want the first, second, fourth and fifth columns into one line but separated by different delimiters..

For example line 1 would be:
1;2:4-5
Line 2 would be:
7;8:10-11
Line 3 would be:
13;14:16-17

I think with the same delimiter the command would be something like:

```
paste --delimiter=':' <(cut -f1 file.txt) <(cut-f2 file.txt) <(cut -f4 file.txt) <(cut -f5 file.txt)
```

The result should be in an array such that each line is a separate entry in the array

```
IFS='\n'; echo "${array[*]}"

1;2:4-5
7;8:10-11
13;14:16-17
```

I'm thinking awk might be able to achieve this but I'm unable to come up with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make awk print each line like you specified, use

```
awk '{ print $1 ";" $2 ":" $4 "-" $5 }' filename
```

Or, to exclude the header line,

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print $1 ";" $2 ":" $4 "-" $5 }' filename
```

To get the results of that into a bash array:

```
while IFS='\n' read line; do array+=("$line"); done < <(awk '{ print $1 ";" $2 ":" $4 "-" $5 }' filename)
```

Comment: Might be cleaner to do `printf("%s;%s:%s-%s\n", $1, $2, $4, $5)`

Comment: Hi, what is the new delimiter I want is a slash "/" ?  `awk` will recognize it as a divide operation.

Comment: Put the slash in quotes, like all the others. awk doesn't see `"-"` as a subtraction operator, it's not going to see `"/"` as a division operator.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use sed if you alway has 4 fields

```
line="1 2 3 4 5 6
> 7 8 9 10 11 12
> 13 14 15 16 17 18 "
echo "$line" | cut -f1,2,4,5 -d " " | sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/\1\;\2\:\3\-\4/g '
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -lanE 'printf "%s;%s:%s-%s\n",@F[0,1,3,4]' file
```

prints

```
c1;c2:c4-c5
1;2:4-5
7;8:10-11
13;14:16-17
```

skipping header

```
perl -lanE 'printf "%s;%s:%s-%s\n",@F[0,1,3,4] if $.>1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell script:

```
while read x ; do set - $x ; echo "$1;$2:$4-$5" ; done < filename
1;2:4-5
7;8:10-11
13;14:16-17
```